# Javascript:void(0) meaning

Tags: javascript

I am curious about one thing to happen : when I hover a link in the bottom of the page there appears something like javascript:void(0);
What does that mean ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined.

Usually, when you want to add a link that has an "onclick" function(and no href) you will do something like this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='doSomething()'>Click Me</a>
```

Clicking on this will return an undefined href and no navigate, but the onclick function will happen.

Read this:[Void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).